# Notepad++ find tag and replace line to upper cases

Tags: notepad++

i have xml file. It contains like the following:

```
<name> big company</name>
<address> 15/F, 1219TH YORK STREET, dale shreedwood </address>
<date> 2023/15/19</date>
<info_num>14256</info_num>
<name> SMALL COMPANY</name>
<address> 12/F, 1220TH YORK STREET, YORKSHIRE KIT </address>
<date> 2023/15/19</date>
<info_num>14256</info_num>
<name> WE COMPANY</name>
<address> 12/F, 5TH YORK1 STREET, Ononl line  KIT </address>
<date> 2023/15/19</date>
<info_num>14256</info_num>
```

change to all content of address field only into uppercase like:

```
<name> big company</name>
<address> 15/F, 1219TH YORK STREET, DALE SHREDWOOD </address>
<date> 2023/15/19</date>
<info_num>14256</info_num>
<name> SMALL COMPANY</name>
<address> 12/F, 1220TH YORK STREET, YORKSHIRE KIT </address>
<date> 2023/15/19</date>
<info_num>14256</info_num>
<name> WE COMPANY</name>
<address> 12/F, 5TH YORK1 STREET, ONONL LINE  KIT </address>
<date> 2023/15/19</date>
<info_num>14256</info_num>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: if the address field has this &amp;   like this <address> 12/F, 5&amp;6TH YORK1 STREET, Ononl line  KIT </address>
<date> 2023/15/19</date>..... how can i not uppercase for this string.?  <address> 12/F, 5&amp;6TH YORK1 STREET, ONONL LINE  KIT </address>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<address>\K(.+)(?=<)`
- Replace with: `\U\1`
- Search mode: `Regular expression`
- Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

[image]

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds!

Comment: @Toto This is a rare occasion when that happens :)

Comment: @momo Please mark the answer as solved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).